# How can I rearrange the order of items in this template, using Perl?

Tags: perl

**How can you convert the following matches to the given result?**

My files have the following matches

```
-- cut --
Lorem ipsun Hello lorem ipsun { $hello } 
@param integer $question_id                   // example of the match
Lorem ipsun Hello lorem ipsun { $hello } 
-- cut --
```

I would like to change them efficiently to

```
@param $question_id integer
```

**My attempt in pseudo-code**

```
perl -i.bak -pe `s/(@param) (\\w) ($\\w)/$1 $3 $2/`
```

Comment: stands the @-sign in the text for a parameter that you fill in or for the string "@param", same question with $-sign by $question-id

Comment: @Commusoft: @param is a sign in the question similarly as $ in $question_id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean (assuming bash shell):

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(\@param) (\w+) (\$\w+)/$1 $3 $2/'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You just saved me a day of production time :)

Answer (score 2):

I would probably either go very generic:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/^(\@param)(\s+)(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)/$1$2$5$4$3/'
```

or very specific:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/^(\@param)(\s+)(\$[_a-zA-Z]\w*)(\s+)(integer|long|char)(\s+)$/$1$2$5$4$3$6/'
```

depending on the data.  The things to watch out for are the string interpolation of $identifier in the shell and the string interpolations of `@param` and `$identifier` in Perl.  The first is handled by using single quotes on the shell (to prevent interpolation) and the second is handled by escaping the `@` and the `$` (or using a character class that avoid having to explicitly match the `$`).

Answer (score 1):

```
s/(\@param)\s+(\w+)\s+(\$\w+)/$1 $3 $2/g
```